# Ruby on Rails: unable to edit credentials.yml.enc

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services

I've run EDITOR=atom rails credentials:edit, edit the file with my AWS credentials, saved then ran rails credentials:show and it still shows the generic 
AWS:

```
access_key_id: 123
secret_access_key: 345
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I am also unable to even find the master.key file anywhere

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)" will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out.  In Atom I have to use `EDITOR="atom --wait" rails credentials:edit` instead of `EDITOR=atom rails credentials:edit`. I don't know why but that worked.  I still don't see a master.key file anywhere but I'll figure that out later.